# React Native Render Error - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, react-native

when I add the card component to app.js it shows the below error:

> ( Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: an object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead ).

I did not add any objects to add keys. In the `AppText` component I have passed only the children props and used them as title and subtitles in the `Card` component

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './app/components/Card';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
      backgroundColor: '#f8f4f4',
      padding: 20,
      paddingTop: 100,
    }}>
      <Card
        title="Item 1"
        subTitle="$50 Million"
        image={require('./app/assets/image/card-img1.jpg')}
      />
   </View>
 );
}
```

this is the `card` component code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../config/colors';
import AppText from './AppText';

function Card(image, title, subTitle) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <Image source={image} />
      <AppText>{title}</AppText>
      <AppText>{subTitle}</AppText>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default Card;
```

this is the `AppText` component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../config/colors';

function AppText({children}) {
  return <Text style={styles.text}>{children}</Text>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: colors.black,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontFamily: 'Avenir',
      },
      android: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      },
    }),
  },
});

export default AppText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Card functional component, you should **destructure** the props that are passed to it.

In addition, the order of the props in declaration and usage should coincide with each other.

**Changes**

*From:*

```
function Card(image, title, subTitle)
```

*To:*

```
function Card({title, subtTitle, image})
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple change, make it work!

change your Card component definition from:

```
function Card(image, title, subTitle) {
```

to

```
function Card({image, title, subTitle}) {
```

##### Explanation:

When you want to pass property to a component, the input parameter of your component will be `porps`, if you want to destruct these props, you need to put a `{}` (the props is an object):

```
const myObject = {name: 'testName', title: 'testTitle'}

const {name, title} = myObject
```